# Opposite of change?

Tags: antonyms

What is the opposite of change (*change* as in "change for currency")?

If I say, "Give me change for $10" what is the opposite of 'change' in that sentence?

Comment: I know of no general-purpose word that functions as an "opposite" in this context. If I had two $5 bills, or a $5 and five ones, I would say something along the lines of, "Can you give me a ten for some change?" or "Do you have a $10 I could trade for some smaller bills?" [Related](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7pMYHn-1yA).

Comment: Can you explain in more words than one what the `opposite` would be in your words? `Change` means `what is left over after you subtract what is yours`. How can there be an opposite of that?

Comment: In the US, most people would say *Can you give me **big bills** (or **bigger bills**)?*

Comment: Literally, the opposite of "change" in that sentence would be "exchange."  In other words, you give the change back to the person from whom you received it!  (I'm only half-joking!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question isn't clear, but in Britain the way of saying "Take these coins and give me ...." [from comments] would be

> Can you change ten pound coins for notes?

When changing currency into coins, you don't need to specify the result because the **noun** *change* means *coins*. But if you want a different result from the exchange, you need to state that explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

In American English, one common word is *break* ("break a ten, get $10 in change"). The opposite is *cashing out* — exchanging smaller currency for larger denominations. E.g. "cash out your register", "cash out his tips", "can you cash me out." The term originally refers to poker — exchanging poker chips back into cash money.

Comment: So there's a (multi-word) verb but no noun? (I don't even think the verb is used in the UK.)

Comment: That phrase is the closest antonym I know of, but I was thinking of antonyms to the verb, "make change."

As a noun, if "change" means coin, the alternative would be bills. ... don't think that's what you had in mind, though...

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be bills or dollars or pounds etc.

Here is the sentence;  "Instead of change for my refund can I get it in bills?"

The opposite "Instead of dollars for my refund can I get it in change?"

Answer (score 0):

**Cash**

Your example:

> Give me change for $10.

Becomes:

> Give me cash for $10 in change.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the word *difference* to specify change.

Example)

```
A: "Your total comes to seven dollars."
B: "Here's a ten, keep the difference."
```